# python error: near "From": syntax error

Tags: python, syntax-error, python-3.5

I am trying to insert 6 values into separate columns in a database and when running my code i'm getting the near "From" syntax error can someone help?

```
def setup_transactions(db, filename):
    '''(str, str) -> NoneType
    Create and populate the Transactions table for database db using the
    contents of the file named filename.'''

    data_file = open(filename)
    con =  sqlite3.connect(db)
    cur = con.cursor()

    # create and populate the table here
    cur.execute('CREATE TABLE Transactions(Date TEXT, Number TEXT, Type     TEXT, From TEXT, To TEXT, Amount REAL)')

    for line in data_file:
        data = line.split()
        cur.execute('INSERT INTO Accounts VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', (data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3], data[4], data[5]))
    data_file.close()
    cur.close()
    con.commit()
    con.close()
```

the error is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Python Shell, prompt 2, line 1
  File "/Users/user1/Desktop/assignment 2/banking.py", line 64, in 
    cur.execute('CREATE TABLE Transactions(Date TEXT, Number TEXT, Type TEXT, From TEXT, To TEXT, Amount REAL)')
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "From": syntax error

Comment: from is keyword in sql, be more descriptive with the column name, IE: `From_Something`

Comment: But im not calling the data im inserting i dont use From at all.

Comment: Please copy the error trace

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cur.execute('CREATE TABLE Transactions(Date TEXT, Number TEXT, Type TEXT, From TEXT, To TEXT, Amount REAL)')`

You have a column named From. From is a sql Keyword, I would avoid using it as it may cause syntax errors

Try something more descriptive like

`cur.execute('CREATE TABLE Transactions(date_created TEXT, current_Number TEXT, record_type TEXT, from_somewhere TEXT, to_somewhere TEXT, amount REAL)')`

Comment: and so is Date, and Number probably even shadows a data_type

Comment: @AharonSnyder Accept answers when complete. Other users may have similar questions in the future!

Comment: it says i need to wait 4 minutes to accept the answer. But i will

Comment: You can quote the column names if you really want to use those exact names, but this may be more trouble than it's worth.